# Store Array of Ints in Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am trying to store an array of Ints in Core Data. I have configured my model with:

Entity: `Performance`
Attribute: `secondsSinceStart`: `Transformable`

Within the Xcode Data Model Inspector panel I have set the attribute's custom class as `[Int]`

Since setting the custom class, Xcode produces the following warning:

```
file:///....xcdatamodel: warning: Misconfigured Property:
Performance.secondsSinceStart is using a nil or insecure value transformer.
Please switch to NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName or a custom NSValueTransformer subclass of NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer
```

What do I need to do to satisfy this warning?

I have tried to "Create NSManagedObject Subclass" for this entity, but Xcode then gives an error that `Multiple commands produce ....'Performance+CoreDataProperties.o'`

Comment: If you have generated a subclass manually then you need to clean the build folder or there will already exist a built version of that class.